# Emacs Org Mode: Executing simple python code

Tags: python, emacs, org-mode

How can I execute very simple Python-Code in Emacs' Org Mode?

The first example works fine, however I can't make it give me the result of simplest computations:

```
; works
#+begin_src python
def foo(x):
  if x>0:
    return x+10

  else:
    return x-1

return foo(50)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 60

; does not work
#+begin_src python
1+1
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: None

; does not work
#+begin_src python
print(1+1)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: None
```

I set up Org Mode using the following lines:

```
;; enable python for in-buffer evaluation
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((python . t)))

;; all python code be safe
(defun my-org-confirm-babel-evaluate (lang body)
(not (string= lang "python")))
(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate 'my-org-confirm-babel-evaluate)
```

Comment: Try `return print(1+1)` perhaps? This `return` seems "extra" in the original code (outside of the function).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are [two ways](http://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-evaluation.html) of getting
the result of a source block - `output` and `value`. You mixed them up, hence the troubles.

First block is fine.

To fix the second block:

```
#+begin_src python :results value
return 1+1
#+end_src
```

To fix the third block:

```
#+begin_src python :results output
print 1+1
#+end_src
```

When output mode is `value` you must `return`. Just putting it there like you did
with `1+1` won't do.
In the third one you want the result to be printed output, but your default session
setting is `value`(mine defaults to `output` btw).

And this bit about `org-confirm-babel-evaluate` is kind of irrelevant to the question.
I just have it set to `nil`.

Comment: Do we required to use `:results value`?

Answer (score 3):

You may still face problems like blank lines cause error in function definition. The solution is given in [original thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-03/msg00405.html). I also posted below

```
(setq org-babel-python-command "ipython3 --no-banner --classic --no-confirm-exit")

;; use %cpaste to paste code into ipython in org mode
(defadvice org-babel-python-evaluate-session
(around org-python-use-cpaste
        (session body &optional result-type result-params) activate)
        "Add a %cpaste and '--' to the body, so that ipython does the right thing."
(setq body (concat "%cpaste\n" body "\n--"))
ad-do-it
(if (stringp ad-return-value)
  (setq ad-return-value (replace-regexp-in-string "\\(^Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D\.[\r\n]:*\\)" "" ad-return-value))))
```

Comment: that works great @bowen.li , can you get inline plotting with matplotlib?