# using babel org mode on emacs as a python data analysis environment

Tags: python, emacs, anaconda, org-mode, org-babel

I've started using `org-babel` on `emacs` 25.3.1. for my initialization file and for organizing.
I am using `ein` to run `jupyter notebook` and wanted to know if it is possible to use `org-babel` in the same way.

The `ein` notebook I use for data analysis using the `numpy`, `pandas`, and `matplotlib` python libraries, It works very well but [seeing examples to similar work done with `R` and `gnuplot` on babel in `org-mode`](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/uses.html) I wonder if it can work for `python` analytics packages.

[Here is a link](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/intro.html#literate-programming) to babel's short documentation, the introduction to literate programming with a few snippets of code in different languages.

I use Python version 3.5.4 `anaconda` which conveniently installs all the libraries and with anaconda-mode on `emacs` I have access to all functionalities, yet in babel:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output
import numpy
arr = np.arange(10).reshape(2, 5)
a
#+END_SRC
```

This code in the org file doesn't really see the anaconda installation since it uses the emacs python-mode, I think,  and therefore doesn't import numpy...

I like the idea of literate programming, it might be less useful than a notebook with code cells and markdown cells but considering the customizable nature of `org-mode`, it can be very interesting to work in that enviornment.

**EDIT starting here**

I found [this implementation in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18598870/emacs-org-mode-executing-simple-python-code?rq=1) the answer by @bowen.li  has useful code for changing the interperter to ipython and therefore have access to the missing libraries. I am still looking for ways to implement more functionality, like inline plotting with matplotlib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think anaconda has anything to do with it: your script is buggy. If I do:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(10).reshape(2, 5)
print(a)
#+END_SRC
```

I get

```
#+RESULTS:
: [[0 1 2 3 4]
:  [5 6 7 8 9]]
```

You do need to load `ob-python` in order to use babel with python, but that's standard: you need to load `ob-XXX` in order to use babel with XXX in general.

John Kitchin uses python and org-mode (among many other things) extensively. You might want to visit his [blog archive](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/archive/) and browse.

Comment: thanks @Nick , I have just installed ob-ipython and ran into some new problems... so I'm reading through the github issues. Thanks for the link, the John Kitchin blog looks fascinating.